# Stop onclick func of span to get called when user clicks on dropdown inside it

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

I am new to web-dev area and am working on a react project.
I have a use case where i have to make a span clickable. But i have a dropdown inside that span which does not have any onClick event registered. When i click on the dropdown then, instead of expanding/collapsing it calls the function registered with span onClick event.
I want to stop call to that function and make dropdown work normal like it would outside that span. Any suggestions?

Thank You.

Comment: stop the propagation of  the event with ```event.stopPropagation()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `event` param of onClick event

```
onClick (event) {
  event.stopPropagation()
  // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

on the method of your click in span pass an event

```
handleClick = (e) => {
e.stopPropagation()
//your logic here
}

<span onClick={(e) => {this.handleClick(e)}}></span>
```